# How to transfer Triviador World app so as not to lose the progress from one device to another without rooting

Tags: applications, data-transfer

I try to transfer Triviador World app so as not to lose the progress from Lenovo (K6 Note) to a Motorola device.
I tried this by using the app Helium. However I found that this up is not compatible with Motorola. So I need something else.
Would you like to share your knowledge in this regard.

Comment: Are you talking about this game? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thxgames.triviador If yes this game seems to allow local backup via adb as well as backup into Google cloud.

Comment: In fact, I want to transfer Triviador Romania as well as Triviador World

Comment: How can I do this via google cloud? @Robert

Comment: Your Lenovo device is a bit old, not sure if cloud backup was already that good on Android 6. Have a Google account active on the device and enable backup to cloud. Then set-up the new device using the same Google account. In the set-up phase the device should ask if data should be restored.